# MySQL length() not giving correct number of characters

Tags: mysql, trim, string-length

I have a table with 8 columns, all varchar (24, 24, 24, 5, 5, 255, 255, 255).

The three important columns are:

```
icd10code (varchar 24)    
icd10codedot (varchar 24)   
icd10length (varchar 5)
```

I wish to convert one column that looks like this - "ABCDEF" to this - "ABC.DEF".

Here is the MySQL query used, and it worked perfectly!

```
UPDATE icd10
 SET icd10codedot =
 CONCAT (     LEFT(icd10code, 3) ,
              "." ,
              RIGHT( icd10code, ( LENGTH(icd10code)-3 )
                    )
        );
```

All 91,000 rows came out nice EXCEPT there was a trailing "." at the end of those entries that only had 3 characters - like this: "ABC.".
I don't want that dot at the end.

So I tried this:

```
UPDATE icd10 SET icd10codedot = LEFT(icd10codedot, 3) WHERE LENGTH(icd10codedot)=4;
```

and this:

```
UPDATE icd10 SET icd10codedot = LEFT(icd10code, 3) WHERE LENGTH(icd10code)=3;
```

and this:

```
UPDATE icd10 SET icd10codedot = LEFT(icd10code, 3) WHERE LENGTH(icd10code)=3;
```

and none of them worked (a bunch of other combinations were also run, but none worked).

So to see how things were doing in the code, I made a column called "icd10length" varchar int and did this query:

```
UPDATE icd10 SET icd10length = LENGTH(icd10code);
```

and all I got was 91,000 "7"s lined up on the right of the column.

I changed the column from INT to VARCHAR 5, and reran the query and got 91000 "7"'s lined up on the RIGHT of the column ( :-) ).

So two questions:

1. How can I get the correct length of the variable icd10code or icd10codedot into a column?
2. Do you have a slick way of clipping the last character of a string that is 4 characters long?

Thanks very much again!

PS - I tried the initial query in PHP and it crashed - timing out after 300 seconds. Found on the web that you should always do things in MySQL whenever possible.

PSS - I'm doing all of this via phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be causing your problem but `LENGTH` in MySQL gives the length of the string in bytes. `CHAR_LENGTH` gives the character count.

Comment: Yeah, I actually tried both, I should have mentioned that. If I had to bet the problem is in the way I'm doing the query. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Can you make a fiddle which reproduces the problem?

Comment: What happens if you `SELECT icd10code, LENGTH(RTRIM(icd10code) FROM icd10 WHERE LENGTH(RTRIM(icd10code) <> 7`  ? If you get any records it means your column is loaded with trailing blanks after the dx codes. The `RTRIM` function strips blanks from the right of your values.  The `LTRIM` function strips them from the left of your values.

Comment: YOU GOT IT! Thank you, Thank you! Apparently when you upload data from a text file, all of the variables will be space padded on the right to equal the longest variable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have empty space at the end, try using rtrim.

Comment: YES! As I said above, I uploaded the data from a text file, and since it was fixed width, the "extra" width is automatically added in spaces. Thanks VERY much. For other noobs like myself, here's the code that worked:UPDATE icd10 SET icd10length=LENGTH(trim(icd10code)) WHERE LENGTH(icd10code)>0. I can also use this concept to trim the extra spaces off in the entire DB. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: EVERYTHING is fixed! I was able to trim spaces from the whole column and trim the trailing "." from the code - Again, thank you all very much for the help!